# How can I avoid migrating the wrong sites on a mobile device?

Tags: support, bug, migration, mobile-web

I do quite a lot of moderation via the mobile site (mobile Safari), which mostly works but is occasionally a pretty bad experience.

My newest discovery has to do with migrating off-topic questions. [This question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/97510/how-to-convert-ticks-to-clock-cycles-when-profiling-api-calls) involving interpretation and transformation of `QueryPerformanceCounter` results should have been migrated to Stack Overflow, but accidentally ended up on that site's meta instead.

When migrating (as a moderator), you are presented with a text field to name the destination site. This text field helpfully tries to autocomplete and present a list of possible options, but I've noticed that most of the time that list will not scroll (or cannot be scrolled) on my mobile browser. This wasn't a problem until recently, when enough alternative-language versions of Stack Overflow launched to make Stack Overflow *itself* not show up in the first page of results when "Stack Overflow" is typed in the text field.

Instead I canceled out of the autocomplete and simply left "Stack Overflow" in the text box, and clicked the button to perform the migration. This was apparently interpreted as a request to migrate to the meta site instead.

I'm not sure whether that's a bug (or it's a bug that an exact match isn't preferred to a substring match), or what, but either way it's a pretty cruddy experience. Is there a way to avoid this? Can the site's URL be typed into that box instead, or something?

Comment: Adding the bug tag so that it shows up on our dashboard for further investigation.